# Rewrites with hierarchical taxonomies in permalink

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I am attempting to create a hierarchical list of products in WordPress 3.5.1. For example if the custom post type product was in the custom taxonomy `Outdoor > Garden Tools > Hoses`, these would be the desired permalinks:

`/outdoor/garden-tools/hoses/mega-hose/` (loads the single.php template)

`/outdoor/garden-tools/hoses/` (loads the archive.php template)

What is the best practice approach to achieving this?

I have generated the permalinks with all multiple levels of parent categories successfully for the posts and terms using the `post_type_link` and `term_link` filters respectively. There appears to be a problem with the URL rewriting though as the permalinks return 404 responses, I can't seem to figure out how these requests are functioning (where "xx" can be any string):

`/xx/mega-hose/` (returns mega hose page)

`/xx/xx/mega-hose/` (redirects to /outdoor/garden-tools/hoses/mega-hose/ and returns a 404)

Any help would be much appreciated!